# generate height data from DTED maps

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, postgis-1.5

I have 16 DTED maps of (1 degree x 1 degree). I have to generate combined height matrix of maximum 4 (1 degree x 1 degree) DTED maps in my C++ application.

Can someone suggest to me which open source GIS API I should use in Windows 7?

Thanks in advance.

thanks for your valuable reply, i will try GDAL. I have to analyse radio line of sight for two points for communication, that may lie on two different DTED1 map , but the distance between two points will be maximum 150 to 200 km.

and one thing more, i will get two points from another application, and i have to send all height information matrix (rows * column) of that area, that area may be on same or two different DTED 1 maps.

I am confused about DTED 1 map, Whether it is raster file or vector file, 
How GDAL process it, as a raster or as a vector.

Comment: Do you really just want the full coverage (all the elevations in the grid)? Or do you want to do something with it later? Also, can you tell us what DTED you have (e.g. is it SRTM, and what is the grid interval - if you don't know that, can you tell us where you got it?)

Comment: the file name is 43j.dt1 so I think it is DTED1. I want all height matrix (full coverage) in standard grid interval,  means all rows and columns(may be but not sure 1200 * 1200) contains height data in text file. and yes i have to use it later.

Comment: Rather than add comments, please edit the original question to make it as clear and concise as possible.

Answer (score 2):

It would have been easier to provide some more detail, but based on your question, I'd recommend using the [GDAL library](http://www.gdal.org/index.html). There is a [useful C++ tutorial](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) on how to use it.

Since you're trying to use the whole file, please take note of the special notes in the [DTED format description](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_dted.html).

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply, i will try GDAL. I have to analyse radio line of sight for two points for communication, that may lie on two different DTED1 map , but the distance between two points will be maximum 150 to 200 km.

Comment: @prit: Please put this information back into the question, because its really about the requirements, not about the particular answer I'm proposing. Then I can look to rewrite the answer.